# Show $E(T^r) = e^{r\mu +\frac{r^2 \sigma^2}{2}}$ in a lognormal distribution.

Tags: statistics

I'm asked to prove that, if $T$ follows the $LN(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then

$$E(T^r) = \exp\left(r\mu+ \frac{r^2\sigma^2}{2}\right)$$

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean with $(rμ, \frac{r^2σ^2}{2})$. Is there correctly a comma?

Comment: @JimmyR. The title shows a $+$ instead of the comma.

Comment: A$+$, sorry.. It displays correctly to me :/

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628681/how-to-compute-moments-of-log-normal-distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find an answer here ([How to compute moments of log normal distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/628681)).

The keyword you should have used is "$r$-th **moment**".

N.B.: lognormal distribution has no moment generating function ([Proving that the lognormal distribution has no moment generating function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/503165)).

Answer (score 2):

If $T$ follows a log normal distribution, then $\log(T)$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^{2}$.

So $E[T^{r}] = E[e^{\log(T^{r})}] = E[e^{r\log(T)}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }\sigma}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{rx}e^{-(x- \mu)^{2}/\sigma^{2}}\,dx$.

A standard trick is now to work with the integral's exponent and complete the square on it:

\begin{split} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }\sigma}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{rx}e^{-(x- \mu)^{2}/\sigma^{2}}\,dx &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }\sigma}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{(-(x- \mu)^{2}/\sigma^{2}) + rx}\,dx\\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }\sigma}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}((x- \mu)^{2} - \sigma^{2}rx)} \,dx \\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }\sigma}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}((x^{2} -2\mu x + \mu^{2} - \sigma^{2}rx)} \,dx \\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }\sigma}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}((x^{2}+ (-2\mu - \sigma^{2}r)x + \mu^{2})} \,dx \\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }\sigma}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}((\underbrace{x^{2}+ (-2\mu - \sigma^{2}r)x + (\frac{(-2\mu - \sigma^{2}r)}{2})^{2}}_{(x - (2\mu + \sigma^{2}r)/2)^{2} } - (\frac{(-2\mu - \sigma^{2}r)}{2})^{2} + \mu^{2})} \,dx \\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }\sigma}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}((x - (2\mu + \sigma^{2}r)/2)^{2})} \underbrace{e^{\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}((\frac{(-2\mu - \sigma^{2}r)}{2})^{2} - \mu^{2})}}_{e^{[(-\mu/\sigma)+ (- \sigma r/2)]^{2}- \frac{\mu^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}}} \,dx   \end{split}

Since $[(-\mu/\sigma)+ (- \sigma r/2)]^{2} - \frac{\mu^{2}}{\sigma^{2}} = \frac{\mu^{2}}{\sigma^{2}} + \frac{\sigma^{2}r^{2}}{4} + \mu r - \frac{\mu^{2}}{\sigma^{2}} = \frac{\sigma^{2}r^{2}}{4} + \mu r  $ the last line becomes:

$$ e^{\frac{\sigma^{2}r^{2}}{4} + \mu r} \underbrace{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }\sigma}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}((x - (2\mu + \sigma^{2}r)/2)^{2})}  \,dx}_{1} = e^{\frac{\sigma^{2}r^{2}}{4} + \mu r}$$

So, $E[T^{r}] = e^{\frac{\sigma^{2}r^{2}}{4} + \mu r}$.

Comment: There is a small typo somewhere in my calculations since the denominator in the final answer should be $2$ not $4$.  I will look for it and fix it when I find it.  You should also look for it as you do this calculation on your own.

Comment: I figured out the issue.  The PDF for the normal distribution is wrong.  There should be a factor of $2$ in the denominator of the power of $e$ (so instead of $\sigma^{2}$ it should be $2\sigma^{2}$.